# Automatically USB mount in /media/usb/LABEL and remove mountpoint after unplug (w/o unmount)

Tags: server, usb, mount, samba, unmount

I'm building a little homeserver for a friend and he wants this as simple as it can get - so without the use of command line / ssh.

Everything works fine now. I installed Ubuntu Server 17.10, Nextcloud, a simple DLNA Server and created a Samba share.

Now he wants to connect USB disks and sticks to the server for sharing them inside his network.

Now I have two:
1. How do I manage, that the server will create a mountpoint with the label or device name under /media/usb/LABEL when a usb disk is connected and remove the mountpoint when the device is getting disconnected?
2. Is it possible to just unplug the usb device WITHOUT the need of manual unmount or safely remove? If not, is it possible to do this over a network share?

I tried usbmount and this worked for creating a correct mountpoint under /media/usb0-7 and a symlink to the mountpoint /media/usb/LABEL. But it doesn't remove the symlink for the mountpoint.
After some searching, I found out, that usbmount won't create a symlink under /var/run/usbmount, but after reading all scripts, it should do this.

I hope you understand, what I want to do.

Greetings from Germany,
Jannomag

Comment: No, it is risky to just unplug the usb device WITHOUT manual unmount. If the buffers are not yet flushed, some files might not be written and the whole file system in the USB drives might be corrupted. You could make a shellscript, that performs the unmount and after that removes the symlink (and make your friend use that shellscript).

Comment: He won't use this script, because he is only a simple user - it's very complicated to explain him simple things deeper than the normal use of Windows for work and surfing. But he wanted the server and now I'm trying my best :D But I have an idea - shouldn't it be possible to press the homebutton and run a script?

Comment: Do you expect him to manage the server via `ssh` or via a GUI? Or do you want a system, that is fully automatic? If you want to unplug the usb device WITHOUT manual unmount, it should be mounted **read-only**. Then there would be nothing in the buffers, that need flushing (at the unmounting). Otherwise, I'm sorry, there is no shortcut. Even Windows needs unmounting alias safe removal ;-)

Comment: Never used the safe removal in windows with flash drives - didn't note any lost, but I had data lost with ubuntu years ago. The server should nearly everything automatic, if there are problems I will login remotely to solve them. And read-only is not good, this is a point he won't understand...any chance to get a web interface for mounting and unmounting usb devices next to nextcloud? This could be another solution.

Comment: You can create a desktop file, which runs a script, and the desktop file can be activated via a hotkey (a key or key combination), at least if the server is running a graphical desktop environment (which is possible via `ssh -X`).

Comment: No GUI for the server, just CLI - and just for me - my friend's GUI will be Nextcloud only :D

Comment: Maybe your friend can plug the USB drives into his client computer instead and use the available tool for {unmounting/safe removal}.

Comment: Okay - after asking in two German forums without any answers and after reading your answers, I tell him, that he can connect USB if he want, but it's possible that there is some data loss if he disconnect it. Now I'm using this script: https://github.com/six-k/automount-usb and it's working good. I shared the /media/ via Samba and added it to Nextcloud.

Comment: I forgot: Thanks for the answers! Without this site I never managed to install my own Ubuntu server - I just didn't need to ask questions here :D

Comment: Your friend can keep the USB drives connected until the server is shut down (tell him to make a 'soft' shutdown is the correct way, the buffers will be flushed in the shutdown process). -- You are welcome and good luck to you and your friend using the server :-)

Comment: The server will run 24/7 with a weekly update job with reboot on Sunday 4.00 am. Maybe I'll do some energy saving at night time with hibernate, but this is future, he has to take a look at the power consumption and the electric bill :D